# How to use localStorage in typescript?

Tags: typescript, local-storage

If I try to assign `item` (item is an object) to `Product` by the following code:

```
localStorage.setItem("Product",JSON.stringify(item))
```

Then `Product`  does not get assigned to the `item` JSON string.

Any resolution to this?

Comment: can you please share more snippet or create a stackblitz? Working local storage example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-x1cbff

Comment: @SiddharthPal is correct: we need more information because that should work fine

Comment: @SiddharthPal thanks a lot.your code worked.I forgot to use getItem to check if the localStorage has picked up the value or not

Answer (score 0):

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-x1cbff)
to retrieve `console.log(localStorage.getItem("Product"));`